# Problem with get_permalink, to get page content

Tags: permalinks

I want to retrieve the content of a page via ajax. but i have a problem with get_permalink

```
<?php
    $id = 171; 
    $post = get_post($id); 
?>
<a class="post-link" rel="" href="<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>">
```

when I echo the permalink it gives me this address

```
 https://mysite/2018/11/24/152-revision-v1
```

If I click in the link it gives me a page not found.
If I copy paste it in the url a page not found shows.
I verify the guid in the database and is the same that permalink gives me. 
When I watch a page in the address bar in chrome only shows me https://mysite/mypage/

Other thing I had notice in the database is that the post id change every time the page content is edited, how I can search for the id of page if it always change?

Comment: I think the issue is permalink, go to settings and set the permalink to post name and save it

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in your question already...

When you use `get_permalink` for your post 171, it gets you

```
https://mysite/2018/11/24/152-revision-v1
```

So, as you can see, this post is not a published post, but a revision of a post. Revisions are not public, so you can't see them...

**So how to solve that?**

You'll have to check the correct ID of a post you want to link to and replace `171` with that ID.